# Another void C# question

Tags: c#

Have a type in the header files I'm working with called VTVOID it is the type of a struct element and a number of parameters.
In the header file defining types is the line

```
#define VTVOID   void
```

I read in another discussion the void maps to `System.Void` however when I plug that into the C# code I get the error

> "System.Void cannot be used in C# --
>   use typeof(void) to get the void
>   object."

So what type do I plug in?
Jim

Comment: Uhh, does `typeof(void)` not work?

Comment: You're saying that #define VTVOID void works, so what are you trying to change?

Comment: why not use System.Object ? ;)

Comment: @John How did you understand what @Jim was actually asking?

Comment: It would help to see the actual structure definition.

Comment: @Anton - I don't really, I just assume it's a C# call to some unmanaged API that requires a type

Answer (score 2):

use void Foo(){} instead of System.Void Foo(){} if the return vlaue void is meant.

use byte[] instead of void* if you need to have an array of data.

Comment: VTVOID is used both as struct element type as follows:
   [StrucLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=4)]
   public struct DAFILESPEC {
     public VTDWORD dwSpecType;
     public VTVOID pSpec;
     Public IntPtr hThis;
    };
And as a parameter type
    [DllImport("sccda.dll")]
    public static extern uint DADeInit(VTVOID param0);
Above output from PInvoke Wizard 2.0 and I'm subbing in the C# compatible types. e.g. VTDWORD is a uint on 32 bit machine.
Other comments:
#define VTVOID void is the C header file not C#
Did System.Type VTV = typeof(void) couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: This is strange, you cannot declare a variable as void. From the name of the variable "pSpec" I would guess from the prefix that it is a **pointer** to void. The method which has VTVOID as only argument I would guess that this method has no parameters.

Comment: as you can see here the method DADeInit has no parameters: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14154_01/sxguide/html/c04_dataaccess003.htm